# Adding NSScrollView to IKImageBrowserView for scrolling

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview, ikimagebrowserview

I am using Xcode 4.4 on MacOSX 10.8. I am trying to add a NSScrollView to IKImageBrowserView for vertical scrolling feature. I have added IKImageBrowserView on top of NSScrollView in IB and in the code:

```
[self.scroll_View setDocumentView:self.image_BrowserView];
```

But I don't get a vertical scrolling feature after adding images to IKImageBrowserView. I see the scrollView behind the ImageBrowserView but no scroll.
   I have also set :
`[self.window setContentView:scrollCurrentList_View];`

I also saw some posts saying NSBackingStoreRetained on NSWindow. Is their some simple way of adding a vertical scroll to IKImageBrowserView to see the images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your `IKImageBrowserView` in IB then select editor menu 
 then in embed menu item select scroll view
 like this

[image]

then select scroll view IB

In attributes enable vertical scroller

like this

[image]